# Oracle database order by Polish characters

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I have problem with sorting elements by varchar containing Polish characters like ą, Ą.

For example, we have following names:

```
Aaaa
BBcvx
Ąccc
Ddde
ądcc
```

Following query:

```
select * from something order by lower(name);
```

Returns result as this:

```
Aaaa
BBcvx
Ddde
ądcc
Ąccc
```

As you can see, polish characters are ignored and put at the end. It should be:

```
Aaaa
ądcc
Ąccc
BBcvx
Ddde
```

What might be the problem? Database encoding? Mine is:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

Result:
EE8MSWIN1250
```

Can this be fixed without changing database encoding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look into the [NLS_SORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams153.htm#REFRN10127) parameter, specifically [linguistic sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm). You can use this parameter to specify what [language you'd like to sort by](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/applocaledata.htm#i637232). I suspect in your case it would be `POLISH`.

Something like this

```
select *
  from something
 order by nls_lower(name, 'NLS_SORT' = 'POLISH')
```

[`NLS_LOWER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions111.htm#SQLRF00677) returns a lower case character in the same manner as an ordinary `LOWER()`.

You could also do this at a session level, which would change the default sort parameter for the duration of the session.

```
alter session set nls_sort = POLISH;
```

If you wanted to *always* use this sort; this is done the database level when the database is created.

Comment: +1 I'd have given the same answer but less elaborated than you, thx.

Comment: Can it be combined with Hibernate, say, some property in hibernate.cfg?

Comment: I have no idea @kamil, that would be a separate question, but according to the docs you can use a `.Filter()` to perform an arbitrary sort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer anyway. I'll find solution now, knowing what's the problem ;)